# Is using asp.net validators enough?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

i am using asp.net validation like Required field validator etc. I am wondering is it enough to put these validators or something in backend should be done also ? I mean that it's working absolutely fine but i used to hear that validation should also be done in backend etc because client side validation can be turned off which will cause application to crash ? so is it true ?

e.g.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFrom" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="txtFrom" Display="None" ErrorMessage="" 
                                ForeColor="Red" >
     </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    &nbsp; To :
    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="Calender" Format="dd/MMM/yyyy" runat="server" TargetControlID ="txtFrom"></asp:CalendarExtender>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTo" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
      <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" Format="dd/MMM/yyyy" runat="server" TargetControlID ="txtTo"></asp:CalendarExtender>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValisdator9" runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="txtTo" Display="None" ErrorMessage="" 
                                ForeColor="Red" >
     </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Guys thanks for kind replies i tried to validate page on submission button, like this, is it correct ?

protected void btnGenReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //This Event Generates Report of Complaints Between Specific Dates.

```
    try
    {
       //my report binding code

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message.ToString());
    }

    Page.Validate();
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        txtFrom.Text = "Validated";
    }
    else 
    {
        txtFrom.Text = "NOT VALIDATED";
    }

}
```

Comment: Use `Page.Validate()` on server-side.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I added your comment in my answer. Thanks.

Comment: ok sir but just Page.Validate() ? that's all ?

Comment: @user3518032: Yes, that's all.

Comment: Ok sir, exactly where to put ? in pageload event ? !Postback event ? or any button ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When there is no javascript on the client (unlikely but possible) you could end up with your validations turned off. Also, someone could try to circumvent your checks by posting the data directly to your website.

For these situations you always need server side validation.

According to [MSDN: Validating ASP.NET Server Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479013.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> What makes these validation server controls effective is that when an ASP.NET page containing these controls is requested, it is the ASP.NET engine that decides **whether to perform the validation on the client *or* on the server** depending on the browser that is making the request.

It seems the validation uses one, not both.

You can ensure that the data is valid by calling [`Page.Validate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ke7bxeh(v=vs.110).aspx) as suggested by [Tim Schmelter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/284240/tim-schmelter).

Comment: +1 I hadn't realised that the server side check was done only if JS wasn't available

Comment: Not how I would have done it but never mind. I would have thought the risk/expense of checking whether client side was done outweighs the performance of checking twice.

Comment: thanks a lot, so it mean that by using asp.net validators, i am safe unlike js validators  ? right ?

Comment: Yes. And to be absolutely sure, call `Page.Validate()` inside your server side before handling the content to force server side validation.

Comment: thanks a lot but exactly where to put ? in pageload event ? !Postback event ? or any button ?

Comment: On the event handler of your submit button for example.

Answer (score 2):

Yes because .NET validators contain validation logic on both the client side and server side. As you've pointed out someone can turn off javascript (or just post the information to the page themselves), in this case the client side validation won't fire but the server side logic will still protect you.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kh55542%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> Validation controls perform input checking in server code. When the
>   user submits a page to the server, the validation controls are invoked
>   to check the user input, control by control. If a validation error is
>   detected in any of the input controls, the page itself is set to an
>   invalid state so you can test for validity before your code runs.
>   Validation occurs after page initialization (that is, after view state
>   and postback data have been processed) but before any change or click
>   event handlers are called.

There is a [custom validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5db6z8k(v=vs.90).aspx) where you can add your own validation checks. On this control you must implement the check both on the client and the server for the same reasons.

Comment: thanks a lot, so it mean that by using asp.net validators, i am safe unlike js validators  ? right ?

Comment: @user3518032 correct. JS validators don't run on the server, the .NET ones can if required.

Answer (score 1):

It's true: client-side validation ensures that the data you will get will be valid as long as the user does not mess with the client/forge a response/use another client. However, you can never be sure of this, so you will need to have a server-side validation also.

The good news is that if the data doesn't pass that validation, it means that the client has done something nasty, so you don't have to think of a nice and helpful way to present the error to him.

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph, I can see where you're going but I'd be hesitant. You may end up penalising users of your site who (for whatever reason) don't want to enable JS on their browser.

Comment: thanks a lot, so it mean that by using asp.net validators, i am safe unlike js validators  ? right ?